# How to add data to specific row/column in an excel sheet using python based on a given list?

Tags: python, excel

I have python code that gives data in the following list = [author, item, number]

I want to add this data to an excel file that looks like this: [image: raw excel file].

The python script will:

1. Check if the author given in the list is in the `Author Names` column, and add name if it is not in present.
2. Then the code will add the number in the column that matches the item given.

For example:

['author2', 'Oranges', 300], 300 would be added to Oranges column on the row for author2. 
[image]

If the person adds a list again like ['author2', 'Oranges', 500] and an input already exists for the item, the number will be added together so the final result is 800.

How do I get started with this? I'm mostly confused about how to read columns/rows to find where to insert things.

Comment: Please include your code and attempts on it. It will help people understand your problem statement better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how you might do it:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# Make a dictionary for the authors, that will automatically start all the 
# values at 0 when you try to add a new author
authors = defaultdict(lambda: dict({'Oranges':0, 'Apples':0, 'Peaches':0}))

# Add some items
authors['author1']['Oranges'] += 300
authors['author2']['Peaches'] += 200
authors['author3']['Apples'] += 50
authors['author1']['Apples'] += 20
authors['author2']['Oranges'] += 250
authors['author3']['Apples'] += 100


# Write the output to a csv file, for opening in Excel
with open('authors_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # Write Header
    writer.writerow(['Author Names', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Peaches'])

    for key, val in authors.items():
        writer.writerow(
            [key,
            val['Oranges'], val['Apples'], val['Peaches']
            ])
```

For more details on writing out to CSV's you can see the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Alternatively, just search using DuckDuckGo or your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it appears your spreadsheet is stored externally, and you want to read in some new data from the list format [author, item, number].

Python `pandas` is great for this.  This would read in the data file, lets call it `authorVolumes.xlsx`.  This assumes the spreadsheet is already in the folder we are working in and looks as it does in your first picture.  Also the items are limited to the ones in the spreadsheet already as you did not mention that in the question.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('authorVolumes.xlsx', index_col='Author Names').fillna(0)
print(df)

Author Names Oranges Apples Peaches
author1      0       0      0
author2      0       0      0
author3      0       0      0
author4      0       0      0
author5      0       0      0
```

Now lets define a function to handle the updates.

```
def updateVolumes(author, item, amount):
    try:
       df.loc[author][item] += amount
    except KeyError:
       df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([amount], index=[author], columns=[item])]).fillna(0)
```

Time to handle the first update:`['author2', 'Oranges', 300]`

```
author, item, amount = ['author2', 'Oranges', 300]
updateVolumes(author, item, amount)
```

Now to handle one where the author is not there:

```
author, item, amount = ['author10', 'Apples', 300]
updateVolumes(author, item, amount)
```

When we are done we can save our excel file back out to the files system.
`df.to_excel('authorVolumes.xlsx')`